# Why mass is independent of any measurement like velocities of particle or relative velocity of two frames?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, mass, inertial-frames

In the derivation of relativistic momentum, I came across a equation and a statement after it and I am unable to understand it. The equation is $$m_i^{'}=\frac{m_i\gamma_i^{'}}{\gamma_i}$$
according to this, $m_i$ must be independent of any measurement done in $S$ frame such as $v_i$ or relative velocity of frames **$u$** . Similarly,$m_i$(I think its may be $m_i^{'}$  must be independent of any measurement done in $S^{'}$ frame such as $v_i^{'}$ or relative velocity of frames $u$ to hold law of conservation in $S^{'}$ frame.
If my question is not clear then explain me following equation $$\frac{m_i^{'}}{\gamma_i^{'}}=\frac{m_i}{\gamma_i}= constant(m_o)$$
where $m_o$ is rest mass

Comment: Came across where? Which page?

Comment: Book is from an open University IGNOU in India.